# Is JSON-LD supported by Google?

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets, json-ld

See this page: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/schema-org

> Google is in the process of adding JSON-LD support to more markup-powered features. So far, JSON-LD is supported for all Knowledge Graph features, sitelink search boxes, Event Rich Snippets, and Recipe Rich Snippets; Google recommends the use of JSON-LD for those features. For the remaining Rich Snippets types and breadcrumbs, Google recommends the use of microdata or RDFa.

From this, I understand that I should only use JSON-LD for events and recipes.

However, looking at examples that Google themselves provide for other types (https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/articles#article_markup_properties) it seems they provide JSOn_LD examples.

Also, using their testing tool (https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) seems to work fine.

So, which is it? Did they forget to update the intro page? Or are they giving bad examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Google supports JSON-LD for most things, and I can confirm from personal experience that Google supports JSON-LD Article rich snippet.

If the Structured Data Testing Tool shows ‘All good’ for the rich snippet, it's almost certainly going to be read correctly (but of course Google has no obligation to show it in the SERPs). Google seems to update the tool, then the specific rich snippet page, before any other summary/etc pages which often show archaic/unrecommended features/methods.